# No Bundle URL Present

Tags: react-native-firebase

I am running 5.1.0 of react-native-firebase-starter (https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter/blob/master/package.json)

I have triple checked that I have followed the Getting Started instructions (from the readme) exactly. However, when I run the project I get "No Bundle URL Present".

I have searched for this error elsewhere and seen `rm -rf ios/build/; kill $(lsof -t -i:8081);` as the answer.  I've tried this, and variations, several times but I cannot get the project to run.

Comment: did you configure the build settings ?

Comment: These were my steps: 1.1 - clone | 1.2/3 - install packages | 1.4 - pod install | 1.5 skip for android | 2.0/1/2 - rename and note | 3.1/2 - generate plist file with same name and put in ios directory | 3.3/4 - skip for android | 4.1- npm start | 4.2 npm run ios

These steps came from here: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter#getting-started

Is there some other setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` to my `/etc/hosts` file

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Open a terminal window
- cd into YOUR_PROJECT/ios
- Remove the **build** folder with rm -r build
- Run react-native run-ios again

Answer (score 0):

**I know its an old question but in Future if someone face this issue i have found a work around to this problem.**

1. after running "react-native run-ios" command
2. Run another command "npm start"
3. after running above command you will "Loading dependency graph" wait
   for 2 or three seconds and you will see thisLoading dependency
   graph, done.
4. now press cmd+R **OR** you may tap on reload on screen if problem not
   solved do step 4, 2 to 3 times